# How to speed up "for loop" in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

Below code is running so slow. I tried using `numpy.argwhere` instead of "if statement" to speed up the code and I got a pretty efficient result but it's still very slow. I also tried `numpy.frompyfunc` and `numpy.vectorize` but I failed. What would you suggest to speed up the code below?

```
import numpy as np
import time

time1 = time.time()

n = 1000000
k = 10000

velos = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, n)
line_centers = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, k)
weights = np.random.random_sample(k)
rvs = np.arange(-60, 60, 2)

m = len(rvs)
w = np.arange(10)
M = np.zeros((n, m))
for l, lc in enumerate(line_centers):
    vi = velos - lc

    for j in range(m - 1):
        w = np.argwhere((vi < rvs[j + 1]) & (vi > rvs[j])).T[0]

        M[w, j] = weights[l] * (rvs[j + 1] - vi[w]) / (rvs[j + 1] - rvs[j])
        M[w, j + 1] = weights[l] * (vi[w] - rvs[j]) / (rvs[j + 1] - rvs[j])

time2 = time.time()

print(time2 - time1)
```

***EDIT:***
The size of the array `M`  was incorrect. I fixed it.

Comment: You may want to take a look at numba: http://numba.pydata.org/

Comment: I will take a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use Numba write everything out in a simple nested loop (no vectorized commands like argwhere)

Comment: Note that removing `argwhere` from your code (e.g., replacing it with a constant `w=1`, for example, speeds up the loop by a factor of 20. So if you can rewrite that, your code may already be a lot faster. The nested loop may not matter to much here.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a situation where a c++ interface could come in handy. With Pybind11 you can create c++ functions which take numpy arrays as argument, manipulate them and return them back to python. That would speed up you loops. Take a look at it!

Comment: I thought of writing in C ++ as a wrapper. But then I wondered if It had a solution for python. Pybind11 looks like useful for this purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is slow, you have two nested loops!  You need to rethink your algorithm using vector operations, as in, no iteration over indices, but implement in terms of index or boolean arrays, and index shifts.

You have not given any background information, so it is incredibly hard for anyone to suggest something meaningful (given the soup of indices in the example).  A few quick suggestions based on quickly gleaning over your example.

- An expression like this `(rvs[j + 1] - rvs[j])` is easily replaced with [`numpy.ediff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html#numpy.ediff1d).
- You seem to be iterating through `n` in blocks of `m`, maybe [`numpy.nditer`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.nditer.html) will be of use.
- I have a hunch that your inner loop has an error, are you sure you really mean to iterate over `range(m - 1)`?  That would mean you are iterating from `0` to `m-2` (inclusive), I doubt you meant that.

We can help with more concrete answers if you provide more background information.

Comment: I shared a part from the original code as an example. It is hard to explain what I want to do with this code, so I didn't give sufficient background information, sorry. `range(m - 1)`  is required for `j + 1` index of array `M`. I will try your suggestions and write the result here. Thank you.